# missing argumentent for parameter 'size' in call

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, skspritenode

I had this Swift code in Xcode which worked perfectly:

```
var obstacles = [SKSpriteNode]()
obstacles.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle"))
```

But I wanted to add an element to this array obstacles in order to have something like `obstacles[i].newElement`, so I tested this:

```
class obstacle: SKSpriteNode
{
    var isActive = false
}

var obstacles = [obstacle]()
obstacles.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle"))
obstacles[i].isActive = true
```

But I have an error with the line `obstacles.append(SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Rectangle"))`
 which is: "missing argumentent for parameter 'size' in call", the thing is that I hadn't this error before and I don't know what is the problem.

If you could help me, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have declared the `obstacles` array as containing instances of `obstacle`, but you are trying to append an instance of its superclass, `SKSpriteNode`. Just change that to create an instance of `obstacle` instead:

```
obstacles.append(obstacle(imageNamed: "Rectangle"))
```

Remember that if you have a base class `A` and a subclass of it `B : A`, you can pass an instance of `B` where `A` is expected, but you **cannot** pass `A` where `B` is expected

Side note: by convention, type names in swift start with an uppercase - I suggest you to keep that convention - so it's better to rename your class as `Obstacle`

Answer (score 0):

If you created an Array and specified that the type is Obstacle, you must add an Obstacle object.
[image]